# От какого корня происходит племенное имя Радимичи?

Tags: этимология, история, корень-слова, старая-орфография, историческое-словообразование

Ничего, если я задам вопрос не по американизмам, а по родному, древнерусскому слову? Любопытно, будет ли это ещё кому-то интересно. Ведь это не требует копания в английских словарях — современных источниках "ново-рашинского языка". Так вот, кто знает, какой корень у названия одного из племён наших предков — Радимичей: *рад* или *род*? Сразу прошу не ссылаться на то, что в летописи  XII века было написано: "от предка Радима", поэтому якобы *рад*. Может, его звали Родим. Как имя писалось, а главное — подразумевалось, более тысячи лет назад, наверное, никто не знает. А кто знает — расскажите.

Comment: Вряд ли на вопрос, заданный в такой агрессивной манере, кто-то будет отвечать. "Английские словари", "ново-рашинский язык" и прочее... этта што?

Comment: "это не требует ковыряться" - это не по-русски

Comment: Согласен, с Тиной. хороший вопрос от "распальцовки" автора сильно проигрывает.

Comment: И с вами не могу не согласиться насчет агрессивности манер, хотя тут и не принято отвергать вопросы только на основании мнения об их авторе. Я считаю, что если автор выразил мысль достаточно понятно и не запутался в своих же словах, то надо отвечать по сути.   
Вот когда при всех внешних признаках культуры, спрашивающий сам не очень понимает о свой вопрос. Но последнее - явно не наш нынешний случай.

Comment: @Тина "он требует сделать" и другие формы [требует]+[глагол] - это совершенно нормальное грамматическое словосочетание. По стилистике соглашусь - ложится бугровато. Я рад, что Вы так требовательны к русскому слову. Если бы я написал "в тренде" или "на тренде", или "под трендом", то Вы бы заглотили любой из вариантов, потому что "тренд", или "трэнд", да хоть "трынд" - слово инородное, в русском языке для него управления пока не существует (я надеюсь и не будет), и, что самое обидное, словарь языка-первоисточника тут тоже не поможет. В итоге - дискриминация русских слов и воля для американизмов

Comment: @Niemand Отвечаю: Это Ваш современный язык. Американский суржик, если говорить нейтрально и спокойно. Посмотрите, сколько на этом сайте идет на полном серьёзе обсуждений, как правильно писать на кириллице очередное американское слово. Источниками при этом являются словари английского языка.

Comment: @Niemand (продолжение)А это дикое позорище. По крайней мере, в понимании французов, испанцев, евреев, японцев, исландцев, ирландцев, арабов, китайцев, корейцев, индийцев, короче - почти всех, кроме пигмеев, папуасов и современных русских. При нынешнем безразличии Власти и отечественных словесников к уничтожению русского языка скоро, лет через 15-20, "русский" язык будет собой представлять переписанный на кириллицу словарный корпус англо-американского языка. Может Вы и не против этого?

Comment: @Expert Ваша честь, пока тут дан только один ОТВЕТ. Остальное - это только огрызание озлобленных любителей нерусской словестности. К сожалению, Ваша честь.

Comment: Да-да-да. Не вы первый, не вы последний заполошничаете насчёт уничтожения русского языка и его скорой кончины. Это старо, как мир. Вернее, старо, как русский язык. )))

Comment: @NiemandПозвольте и мне немного «позаполошничать».Меня тоже в свое время учили,что на язык нельзя повлиять искусственно,что язык это организм,способный к самоочищению,что изменения в языке неизбежны.Похоже,профессиональные филологи до сих пор пребывают в этом благодушном убеждении,в результате армию ревнителей чистоты языка пополняют малограмотные шизоиды,видящие главную проблему в количестве иностранных заимствований.По-моему,за последние1/4века произошли существенные изменения в системе языка(предлоги и местоимения это не просто лексические единицы,они лежат в основе самой структуры языка)

Comment: параллельно с сокращением словарного запаса,и не последнюю роль в этом сыграли наши СМИ.Если не принять меры(Например,штрафовать СМИ за ошибки-заодно бы и бюджет пополнили)окончательно в страну дураков превратимся. Молодежь потому и не читает книги,потому и не работает над своим мозгом,что стимула нет:неграмотных берут на работу в СМИ,начитанность и хороший русский язык не входят в список качеств,необходимых для успеха. Скоро литературу 19-20веков придется переводить на «новорусский», только как это сделать? Мощность словарных запасов нового читателя и старого писателя различаются на порядок.

Comment: >> Скоро литературу 19-20веков придется переводить на «новорусский»... Мощность словарных запасов нового читателя и старого писателя различаются на порядок.

Тина, ну всегда же, во все времена молодежь была "не та". А также и девушки раньше были краше, и вода мокрее. А тут ещё чертов интернет...

Так что это всё не аргументы. А старый писатель точно так же не понял бы нового читателя – мы же ему за это не пеняем? Меняются языки, смиритесь.

Comment: Если бы сами собой менялись, тогда делать нечего. Я же вижу искусственность процесса и возможность искусственно на него повлиять(Помните как массово и внезапно наши журналисты начали говорить и писать "в Украине"?) К тому же есть разница между постепенными изменениями и катастрофическими. Я почему то не сомневалась, что вы истолкуете мои слова как старческое брюзжание.

Comment: Молодежь действительно меняется (сейчас она не такая как в 90е–но это тема для серьезного социологического исследования) А вода и в самом деле была мокрее. Например , Шекспир в 16 веке был попсой (театр ведь искусство площадное, а «Глобус» государство не подкармливало). Сравните с попсой теперешней! В общем, смиримся: каждое время и каждое племя имеет того Киркорова, которого заслуживает

Comment: Радимичи, как понимаю, давно уже никому не интересны?!)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И правда, никому почти не интересно русское слово. Все прицепились к какой-то ерунде.)))

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот, и к чему были все эти грубости в адрес автора вопроса? Как и предполагалось с самого начала, Радимичи мало кому из современных любителей нерусской словесности оказались интересны!... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, "Рад" (в одном из значение как минимум) и "род" - это один корень с чередованием гласной А/О, каковых в русском языке множество. Знающие историческую фонетику не должны тому удивляться, в праслявянских основах эти гласные отличаются не качеством, как сейчас, а долготой. Не сомневаюсь, что Радимичи - это что-то имеющее отношение к "родне", не к радости (хотя еще надо разобраться не родственные ли это корни на еще боле древнем уровне). Источнику, хоть вы его от него и открестились, можете верить, в те времена гласные произносились четко, как написано, так и звался (если это конечно не разовый ляп переписчика, во что тоже мало верится), но это, как сказал, ничего не дает в плане морфологии/этимологии. Другое дело, что совершенно не обязательно название племени происходит от личного имени.

Comment: @behemothus Спасибо за ответ! Но Вы в нем только усилили суть вопроса: исходное значение или смысл - род, родня или рад, радость? То, что именно от предка, у меня не вызывает сомнения - это типично для многих народов не только арийских, и у нас он не единственный пример. Но вот, всё-таки - Радим? Или ТОГДА имелось в виду Родим, как бы "родивший"?

Comment: Так я вроде ответил. Я *отвергаю* прямую связь с *радующий*.

Comment: @behemothus Извините, но из "всех признаков" в пользу РОД вы привели только "не сомневаюсь". Это все аргументы? Я не спорю с Вами, я тоже склоняюсь к этому варианту, но хотел бы найти осязаемые подтверждения. Про белорусов - не соглашусь. Во-первых, не 5, а 2 столетия. Во-вторых, и это не аргумент: литературный язык современных арабов тесно связан с мекканским диалектом 5-6 века, т.е. более 1,5 тысячи лет назад.

Comment: В принципе - да. От противного. Ничего другого просто не остается. 
Я показывал прежде всего непротиворечивость перехода "род"<>"рад" поскольку это было едиственный сколько-нибудь осмысленное возражение против "родной" версии. 

А вот против "Радсти" и прочих "Радуг" - достаточно.
Много вы знаете названий племен, пусть даже и не славявянских, образованных от личного имени? А уж от отвлеченного эмоционального состояния - это уж точно только в кино.  
А вот такие вещи как "родня", "родственник" безусловно лежат в основе любого родоплеменного единения. Для меня это куда более весомый аргумет...

Comment: >Про белорусов - не соглашусь. Во-первых, не 5, а 2 столетия.  
  
Племнное деление славян - не позднее X века. 
Кода по-вашему образовался белорусский язык? Не коворя уж об "аканье"? Сразу скажу, что в т.н. "западнорусском" - официальном языке Великого княжества Литовского (кажется, и Речи Посполитой - одним из) этого фонетического явления не фиксировалось.

Comment: @behemothus Если в западнорусском, он же старобелорусский, аканья не было, тогда моя версия не верна. Одно уточнение - не от "радости" или "рода" произошло название племени, а от имени (!) Радим или Родим. И вот тут вопрос: само имя от какого корня или значения.

Comment: @Niemand "Меняются языки, смиритесь." Меняются, но в двух направления: развиваются либо вырождаются. Примеры: арабский-обогащается, развивает свою собственную корневую базу, заимствований почти НЕТ, американизмов НЕТ ВООБЩЕ. Один из богатейших современных языков. Французский-с 1994 "Закон Тубона" идет по тому же пути-американизмы запрещены ЗАКОНОДАТЕЛЬНО.Японский, в 1946 г. проведена чистка языка от американизмов, испанский-американизмов почти нет,иврит-американизмов почти нет,китайский-американизмов НЕТ,турецкий и греческий-проведены чистки от американизмов,исландский-заимствования ЗАПРЕЩЕНЫ

Comment: @Niemand Список языков, которые РАЗВИВАЮТСЯ и остаются самобытными, очень длинный. Второй путь - деградация или постепенное перерождение в другой язык: русский, украинский, языки Восточной Европы, языки народов черной Африки, Океании и др. Кстати, англо-американский язык тоже развивается за счет собственных диалектизмов, жаргонизмов и т.п. До 90-х годов русский язык тоже развивался. Приведите мне примеры РУССКИХ неологизмов за последние 15 лет. Их почти нет, идет планомерное вытеснение славянских корней в архаику. Будущий рашенский язык сохранит только русские предлоги и местоимения.

Comment: @Тина @Niemand Если проблемы иностранных заимствований не существует и на язык нельзя повлиять искусственно, тогда зачем существует Французская академия языка, которая ежегодно выпускает обязательные для СМИ словарики с искусственными ФРАНЦУЗКИМИ неологизмами вместо американизмов? В арабских странах НИ ОДНО издание не напечатает и НИ ОДИН журналист не произнесет ни один американизм, если они работают в рамках арабского литературного языка. Хочешь выпендриваться, пожалуйста - на англоязычный канал или издание. То же в Китае и т.д. Получается, что армия шизоидов - несколько миллиардов человек?

Comment: В очередной раз: "естественность" заполонения американизмами русского языка - это установка советской западнической школы (типа Л.В.Щербы), которая противоречит действительному состоянию дел в отношении ПОДАВЛЯЮЩЕГО числа языков мира. Эта узколобая и компрадорская установка придумана только в отношении русского языка (кстати, из всех славянских языков самого засоренного заимствованиями). В нашем ряду стоят только языки развивающихся племен и народов. Правильнее - недоразвитых, так как заимствования - признак отсталости собственной культуры. Но русские когда-то гордились своей словесностью...